# Polymer Dart 1.0 - Observer not working

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a custom element `<test-object>` which looks like this:

```
@PolymerRegister('test-object')
class TestObject extends PolymerElement with TestBehavior {

  TestObject.created() : super.created() {
  }

}
```

The `TestBehavior`:

```
@reflectable
class TestModel extends JsProxy {

  @Property(notify: true)
  num value = 0;
  PolymerElement _target;

  TestModel(PolymerElement target) {
    _target = target;
  }

  changeBy(num by) {
    value += by;
    _target.set('testModel.value', value);
  }

}

@behavior
abstract class TestBehavior implements PolymerBase {

  @Property(notify: true)
  TestModel testModel;
  PolymerElement _instance;

  static ready(instance) {
    instance._init(instance);
  }

  static created(instance) {
    instance._instance = instance;
  }

  _init(PolymerElement instance) {
    set('testModel', new TestModel(instance));
  }

}
```

My main app looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <style>
    :host {
        display: block;
        @apply(--layout-center-center);
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <div>{{testObject.testModel.value}}</div>
    <test-object id="obj"></test-object>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  @Property(notify: true)
  TestObject testObject = null;

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  ready() {
    set('testObject', testObject = $$('#obj') as TestObject);
  }

  @Listen('click')
  clicked([_]) {
    testObject.testModel.changeBy(1);
  }

  @Observe('testObject.testModel.*')
  valueChanged([_]) {
    window.console.log('Value was changed');
  }

}
```

This is a very simple toy example. I click `<main-app>` which causes the value in testModel to increase (this works). However, `<main-app>` doesn't update the div which should display the value. Also, `valueChanged` is never invoked. 
I want to notify `testObject` about the `value`update in `testModel` and propagate this notification up to `main-app` which than should update its UI via data binding.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a property in model classes, only in components

```
@Property(notify: true)
num value = 0;
```

should just be

```
@reflectable
num value = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set` and `notifyPath` methods should really be called from your element classes, not the models. This actually simplifies your code a lot, and makes everything work as expected as well. Below I have pasted the new `MainApp`, `TestModel`, and `TestBehavior` classes (I also made some other minor edits).

```
@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  // Defines a read-only property (implicit because of the getter).
  @property
  TestObject get testObject => $['obj'];

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  // I added the 2nd optional argument here, to fix a reflectable error
  @Listen('click')
  clicked([_, __]) {
    // Notify directly here, this is the primary change.
    notifyPath('testObject.testModel.value', testObject.testModel.changeBy(1));
  }

  @Observe('testObject.testModel.*')
  valueChanged([_]) {
    window.console.log('Value was changed');
  }

}

// Removed the `_instance` field.
class TestModel extends JsProxy {

  // use @reflectable instead of @Property(notify: true)
  @reflectable
  num value = 0;

  TestModel();

  num changeBy(num by) {
    value += by;
    // Added a return value for convenience
    return value;
  }

}

@behavior
abstract class TestBehavior implements PolymerBase {
  @Property(notify: true)
  TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
}
```